# Edit Delete Update button on the right of gridview asp.net

Tags: gridview

I want to place autogenerated edit delete update buttons on the right.
Is it possible ? Please Help

Answer (score 5):

In the GridView tasks click on `Edit columns` and convert the fields into `templates`. And then place the delete button field at the end

OR

give like this

```
<Columns>

<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" /> 

</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the grid view control,point to the upper right side corner,click it,there is grid view tasks,click on the edit columns,and move the button to the last position at the "selected field" portion(it is possible if 'auto generate field' is false and 'bound field' is activate)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on GridView.Go to edit columns.You can define the order of all columns along with edit,delete links inside this window.